# Could not parse auth token in rest realtime database (firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Realtime Database within my Angular app and am using Firebase. I am trying to fetch data with a token attached as a param in my request as shown in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token) for RestAPI.

However, when I attach a token to the data, I receive back the `401 error` `"could not parse auth token"`.

I have tried this request inside and outside of my code only to get the same result.

The auth token is coming directly from the `AngularFireAuth`, which was created in my `AuthService` on signup:

```
activeUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
...
signup(email: string, password: string, name: string) {
  return this.firebaseAuth.auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(res => {
      res.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: name
      });

      this.handleAuthentication(
        res.user.email,
        res.user.uid,
        res.user.displayName,
        res.user.refreshToken
      );
      return res;
    });
}

handleAuthentication(
  email: string,
  uid: string,
  displayName: string,
  token: string
) {
  const user = new User(email, uid, displayName, token);
  this.activeUser.next(user);
}
...
```

So I am creating a user with AngularFireAuth, and then using `.next` on the `BehaviorSubject` of `activeUser` in order to add the user with the email, uid, token, and display name. This token is then being used in the `fetchWorkouts()` function to get the data from the database.

My current code is:

```
fetchWorkouts() {
  return this.authService.activeUser.pipe(
    take(1),
    exhaustMap(activeUser => {
      return this.http.get<Workout[]>(
        "https://velo-coach-app.firebaseio.com/workouts.json?auth=" + activeUser.token
      );
    }),
   ...
}
```

I have also tried:

```
fetchWorkouts() {
  return this.authService.activeUser.pipe(
    take(1),
    exhaustMap(activeUser => {
      return this.http.get<Workout[]>(
        "https://velo-coach-app.firebaseio.com/workouts.json",
          {
            params: new HttpParams().set('auth', activeUser.token)
          }
        );
      );
    }),
   ...
}
```

I have also tried simply putting the entire token into the browser:
`https://myapp.firebase.io/workouts.json?auth=MYTOKEN`. All of these result in the same problem: `{ "error" : "Could not parse auth token." }`

When I send a Firebase request to get back some workouts with the request as such: `https://myapp.firebase.io/workouts.json?auth=MYTOKEN`, no matter how I send the request, it seems to always give back the same error.

My Realtime Database rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

If I change these rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

and completely remove the token in my http request, then this works. It's only a matter of when those rules are turned on and I am attaching a token to the API request.

Is there something I am missing here? All the StackOverflow questions asking something similar to this are either unanswered, partially answered but not working, or use the deprecated Database Secrets.

Comment: The error message is suggesting that you're not actually passing a Firebase Auth User ID token.  Please edit the question to show exactly how you're getting this value.

Comment: Added this code. The issue still persists even when I manually add the token to the request and submit it in the browser

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  What exactly is the value you're passing?  Is it what you expect?  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I was adding this while your comment appeared. Should have all the code there. I originally didn't include the code because I thought the fact I was attaching the token to the url directly and it still wasn't working, detached my code from the issue at hand and that it may be a firebase issue

Comment: Looks like the issue is the fact that I am using the refresh token...

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong value.  `res.user.refreshToken` is not the ID token.  Refresh tokens are a different thing used to get new ID tokens periodically.

You will have to call [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) to asynchronously get that string value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see now that this the correct one to use. Could you possibly assist me in getting the string value asynchronously from the `getIdToken()`?

Comment: I think the API documentation is pretty clear.  The method returns a promise that resolves with the string you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
`... res.user.getIdToken(true).then(token => { this.handleAuthentication(res.user.email , res.user.uid, res.user.displayName, token ); ...`